# loading image in opencv2.4.6

Tags: opencv, mat

In opencv 2.4.6. I am trying to load a mat image file with a simple code given below. But the image is not loaded as I print the image size, it is showing '0'. Can anybody please tell me , what is going wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    Mat a=imread("C:/image3.jpg");
    cv::Size frame11_size = a.size();
    printf("%d",frame11_size.height);
    return 0;
}
```

**Update:** I solved the problem. The problem was, I was only including all the library,include and additional dependencies in 'debug mode' only. I did not change anything in 'release mode'. When I change the properties in 'release mode' as-well, it worked. thanks all for your kind responses, I am giving '+1' for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be single slash on your image path, and always check whether image is successfully loaded.

```
 Mat a=imread("C:/image3.jpg");

 if(! a.data )  // Check for invalid input
    {
       cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
       return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Haris, thanks for your reply. I tried both single and double slash, everytime it prints "could not open or find the image' . but the imahe is present in C folder.

Comment: Can you load the image from current directory.

Comment: From current directory you can load you image  like Mat a=imread("image3.jpg"), if this is not working check your image name.

Comment: Then it might be some other problem as Michael Burdinov said.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV can't open jpg files by itself. It depends on third parties to do so. Maybe you are missing certain dlls, or maybe your OpenCV installation don't have the right path to them. To test this assumption store your image in other formats. For example pgm or ppm. Those formats does not perform any encoding and just store image buffer in file as is. As a result OpenCV will not need any external libraries to open image in ppm format.

Comment: I tried with .ppm file as well, it returns "could not open or find the image :'( ..

Comment: One more test to be sure that this is not a problem of some wrong path: copy relevant exe and dll files to the same directory with image file, and run exe file. Don't forget to delete any path references from your code, i.e. leave only something like Mat a = imread("image.ppm");